# VB.NET Add Reference vs Reference Paths (why Reference Paths?)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In my previous C# work referencing other assemblies was either done by adding the project for the assembly to your own solution, or referencing .dlls directly in a common build output folder if you didn't want to make your solution too big. Assemblies were written to this output folder by running a build script or building a core solution that built all of the common .dlls.

Where I work now with VB.NET the team takes the second option (though they check the common .dlls into source control rather than build into the output folder...thats one for another day).

When they reference these .dlls in the reference folder, however, they dont usually do it via the Add Reference option in Visual Studio (2008 here), instead they in the project dialog they select References->Reference Paths and add this common reference folder in there. This reference folder is written to the .user file: it is not part of the project and so each time you get the code clean from source control you have to reset it on each project.

Now, no one can explain to me why this is done...its just the way they have always done it. It seems pretty dumb to me, but maybe there is some reason for doing this? Why is this option available and why would anyone choose to add Reference Paths like this?

Thanks!

Comment: That option doesn't add any references, it only sets a directory where the build system will look for a reference assembly if it cannot find the assembly in its original location.  I suppose the real problem is that the build script for the common assemblies doesn't put the assemblies in a predictable output folder location.  Fix that by picking the same location everybody else uses so you don't have to set this option.  Look at the .vbproj file with a text editor for the HintPath property.

Comment: This option does not set the HintPath: it adds an entry into the .user file. Thats why I have to add all the references back when i get a clean cut of the code: the .user files are not in source control, so neither are all the references.

Comment: Yes, I know.  HintPath is set for the assembly reference.  In the .vbproj file.  What do you see?  Put your common assemblies there as well and you don't need this dialog or the .user file.

Comment: I don't think you have read my question...